# Acessar um elemento no dataframes do pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Gostaria de acessar o primeiro elemento do dataframe do pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['2019', '0000', 'protocolo'], ['2020', '1111', 'pedido']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Tentativa:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['2019', '0000'])
```

Erro:

> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: '2019'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O dataframe criado pelo seu código tem a seguinte forma:

```
      0     1          2
0  2019  0000  protocolo
1  2020  1111     pedido
```

Fazendo `df = df.sort_values(by=['2019', '0000'])`, você está tentando acessar as colunas de nome `2019` e `0000`, daí o erro

> KeyError: '2019'

Mas `2019` é um valor, e não o nome de uma coluna.

Uma maneira de acessar diretamente os valores é

```
>>> df[0][0]
2019
>>> df[0].values
array(['2019', '2020'], dtype=object)
>>> df.iloc[0].values
array(['2019', '0000', 'protocolo'], dtype=object)
```